# Php looping white explode to string

Tags: php, string, loops

I am building a PHP that parceles data.

but I ran into the following problem.
Generate a function to get the model names.

```
    function model($model){
    $model = explode('"Models"', $model);
    $model =  $model[1];
    
    $model = explode('</div></div>', $model);
    $model =  $model[0];
    
    $model = explode('bycjqw', $model);
    $nr2 = count($model);
    
    for ($e = 1; $e <= $nr2; $e++) 
        {
            $name= explode('<', $model[$e]);
            $name=  $name[0];
    
            $name= str_replace('-0 gtoSow">', '', $name);
    
            if($name != ''){
                echo('1:'.$name.'<br>');
            }
        }
        $models = implode(',', $name);
        echo('2:'.$models);
        return $models;
}
```

The divided data is ok in 1 I have

> 1: Name_1 1: Name_2 1: Name_3

But in 2 it is empty.

Can someone give me a hand to implode?

Comment: It looks as though you are trying to work with HTML, your approach will be very fragile and may fail if the original source is changed.

Comment: Also, second argument of `implode` is __array__. Is `$name` variable array?

Comment: No, name is a string and the implode needs to be a string.
to be able to save it in a db

Comment: Please open `implode` manual, the description of this function is "`implode` — Join __array__ elements with a string". So you're obviously doing something wrong

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to achieve with the implode function ( as it apparently doesn't do what you think it does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want to keep track of each `$name`, and you can do that using another array which I'm calling `$names`, and then `implode` that later. Below is the same code except for the two lines that I added which are commented above.

```php
function model($model)
{
    $model = explode('"Models"', $model);
    $model = $model[1];

    $model = explode('</div></div>', $model);
    $model = $model[0];

    $model = explode('bycjqw', $model);
    $nr2 = count($model);

    // Names will be stored here
    $names = [];
    for ($e = 1; $e <= $nr2; $e++) {
        $name = explode('<', $model[$e]);
        $name = $name[0];

        $name = str_replace('-0 gtoSow">', '', $name);

        if ($name != '') {
            echo('1:' . $name . '<br>');
            // Store name
            $names[] = $name;
        }
    }
    $models = implode(',', $names);
    echo('2:' . $models);

    return $models;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had not realized that I needed to declare models [] ...